# How to give space in PHP

Tags: php

I want to give space between variable when it print , when i echo it then it shows character without space like :- *Thanks for Submitting Mr/MrsRahulkumar* , I want to give space between name !

```
<?php 

echo $fname;  
echo $lname;
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
echo "Thanks For Submitting Mr/Mrs";`
?>
```

Comment: just add a space to the string: `echo "Thanks For Submitting Mr/Mrs $fname $lname";`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a space between fname and lname and after that. try the following code.

```
<?php
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
echo $fname.' '.$lname.' ';
echo "Thanks For Submitting Mr/Mrs"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add space between the echo of the two variables.

```
<?php 
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];

echo "Thanks For Submitting Mr/Mrs $fname $lname"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable that displays the name formatted with spacing then call the variable where you wish to place it. Just a space or you could use html entity non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

```
    <?php 
       $fname=$_POST['fname'];
       $lname=$_POST['lname'];
       $fullname = $fname.' '.$lname;
       echo "Thanks For Submitting Mr/Mrs ".$fullname;
    ?>

    <?php 
       //using html entity ex.
       $fname=$_POST['fname'];
       $lname=$_POST['lname'];
       $fullname = $fname.'&nbsp;'.$lname;
       echo "Thanks For Submitting Mr/Mrs ".$fullname;
    ?>
```